# Make use of ins 0..1 to limit the domain of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

The goal of this function is to verify that the list X only contains 0's or 1's.

We have been told to make use of ins to declare the domain of the list.

We have a predicate called `verifyLines` where `H` is a list of constraints and `X` a list representing a line. The constraints verify the number of 1's that can follow each other. For example, if `H` contains the number 3, then `X` would have to contain `1,1,1` at some point in the list. The problem isn't the verification of those constraints since we already made a predicate called `valid_seq` who does it for us. Our issue is that we have to verify that we only have 0 or 1 in the `X` list. Is this a proper way to do it? I seem to get the error that an operator is missing when I use it this way.

```
 verifylines(H, X) :-
     X ins 0..1,
     valid_seq(H, X).
```

Edit:
The error in SWI-Prolog
ĀERROR: x:/bureau/tp2_projet2.pl:4:2: Syntax error: Operator expected

The 4th line being the one with `X ins 0..1,`

I added `use_module(library(clpfd)).` on top of my current `verifylines()` but it does not seem to affect the error message... Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I also am not familiar with the usage of libraries in prolog.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to say: "all elements in list X are either 0 or 1" you just say `X ins 0..1`.

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- X = [A,B,C], X ins 0..1.
X = [A, B, C],
A in 0..1,
B in 0..1,
C in 0..1.
```

Maybe you forget to `use_module(library(clpfd))`? because when I don't then I get:

```
?- X = [A,B,C], X ins 0..1.
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: X = [A,B,C], X
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  ins 0..1 .
```

but really you should put better description of your problem and example program and show what your error looks like and all those things which make it possible to reproduce a problem without guessing, because guessing is more difficult, right?

Do you see how I put only what I need to show the error, without other parts of programs and code, just interpreter interaction, and I copy-paste everything so that you can try the same on your computer and if you get the same error at least you know you can reproduce the problem as I see it, and if you can't then it becomes more difficult, but usually it is not as difficult if you show everything. Also in your code in your question you have included a call to a predicate, but you have not included the definition, so no one can run the program you have shown as you can because they don't have the definition.

Comment: Added some information in the question that might help you understand what exactly is the problem. Thank you for taking the time to look into it.

Comment: @Simon-PierreDesjardins If you put it in source file `example.pl` that you consult with `[example].` from interpreter than you need to write in source `:- use_module(...).` or `?- use_module(...).`. You can read the documentation?